# Arch Linux stuck at "Loading version 240" after modifying configs

Tags: virtualization, arch-linux, gpu, linux-kvm, pci

I'm trying to get GPU passthrough to work on a VM. I've been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FI31QDtyy4. The differences between what I did and what he did in the video was modules in mkinitcpio config thingy, I used 'MODULES=(vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd)' instead because the video was a bit outdated.

**So what I did was**

- Add intel_iommu=on in grub params
- Checked that my system supports IOMMU, I ran 'dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU'
- Adding 'options vfio-pci ids=10de:10f0,10de:1b81' to vfio.conf
- Modifying mkinitcpio.conf as described above
- Running 'mkinitcpio -p linux'
- Modifying qemu.conf (prob not related)
- Running 'systemctl enable --now libvirtd' and 'systemctl enable virtlogd.socket'
- Reboot and go back to Windows 10 (NOT DUALBOOTED. I'm running arch off a USB STICK (NOT LIVE USB)) (Tried adding a vm but failed because I didn't do the ntfs-3g thingy)
- Came back from Windows 10 and added 'UUID=061A04D11A04C023 /media/Data/ ntfs-3g defaults 0 0' in fstab
- Changed 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"' to 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on"' in /etc/default/grub
- Rebooted and stuck at "Loading version 240 (when I remove the intel_iommu=on from params, it booted just fine)

First boot that iommu worked, I used my GPU as output. I tried iGPU after GPU didn't work on the last boot (No Signal). Also I've checked Arch's official wiki about PCI passthrough and the steps were pretty similiar

**/etc/mkinitcpio.conf**:

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=(vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd)

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=()

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=()

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck)

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

**/etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf**:

```
options vfio-pci ids=10de:10f0,10de:1b81
```

**Kernel version**: 4.20.10-arch1-1-ARCH

**Hardware info (lshw)**:

````
cube-arch                   
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: B360M-HD3 (Default string)
    vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    version: Default string
    serial: Default string
    width: 4294967295 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1 dmi-3.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Default string sku=Default string uuid=E002D503-5E04-7905-ED06-310700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: B360M HD3
       vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: x.x
       serial: Default string
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: F4
          date: 04/19/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 3a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
             vendor: Fujitsu
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
             vendor: Fujitsu
             physical id: 2
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0```
````

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

I was dumb, I plugged in my display to my GPU, after plugging it into iGPU it worked. Make sure to also make it primary output in your BIOS